# Horizontal align doesn't work in IE

Tags: html, css, alignment

I'm trying to align a div horizontally, but for some reason it's not working in IE... What am I doing wrong?

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="header">
            <img src="logo.png">
        </div>

        <div id="top-nav">
            <ul class="menu">
                <li class="first leaf menu-mlid-471"><a href="">Home</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
body{
   background-color: #fff;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
 }
ul.menu{
   width: 500px;
   margin: auto;
 }
 #header{
   height: 150px;
 }
```

For Firefox, Chrome, Safari,... no problem. It all comes exactly in the middle. But IE refuses to align it properly...

Comment: The ul.menu is centered but your text inside the menu isnt, why not use text-align:center? Fiddle here -> http://jsfiddle.net/kzHfs/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a doctype? Without it, IE reverts to Quirks Mode, which does not support `margin: auto;` centering.

Also, IE < 6 does not support `margin: auto;` centering at all (in case ancient IE browser compliance is particularly important you).

Answer (score 1):

Use below CSS

```
.ie ul.menu{
           width: 500px;
           margin: auto;
           display:block;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But it didn't make any difference... The menu in IE still aligns to the left with no margin auto.

Comment: Yeah, `<div>` tags are displayed block by default.

Answer (score 1):

Try this `.ie ul.menu{
           width: 500px;
           margin-left: auto;
           margin-right:auto;
           display:block;}`

Answer (score 1):

Actually, if you place a border around your menu div, you will see in IE that the DIV is aligned in the center, however, your ul content is not.  Please pop this into your CSS and see what results you get:

```
ul.menu{
width: 500px;
margin: auto;
border:solid black thin;
text-align:center;
}
```

Should work in IE.